# C++, Gnuplot: Create temporary file in RAM and use it in Gnuplot

Tags: c++, gnuplot

I am a beginner in C++. Suppose I have a C++ program that outputs a function, for example `f(x)=x*x`, and I need it evaluated and printed. This can be easily done within the code.

Is it possible to create a temporary file with the result of the evaluation in RAM? As in, it would be an `std::vector`, most likely, so it would reside in the heap (no?).

Then, would it be possible to use `system()` (or anything from within the code) to call `gnuplot` with the file from the memory?

And, as a final whim, can these two be done without an external virtual RAM disk?

Comment: You cannot do what you described without external virtual RAM disk

Comment: Unless the operating lets you create a RAM-disk of some kind on the fly, then no you can't do that. But what is the problem of using a temporary file on a normal already mounted disk or filesystem, like `/tmp` on a POSIX system? GNUplot files are usually relatively small and writing such a file won't be a bottleneck. Also, now when SSD's are common, writing is even faster, and if you have a lot of memory the temporary directory might already be a RAM-disk.

Comment: @GMichael So then, the only way is to create a virtual RAM disk, but then the first two are possible?

Comment: And for your other question, yes if you write the file to a disk you can easily use `system` to run GNUplot using that file.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I'd like to avoid the filesystem thrashing and repeatedly writing/deleting. The graph will only use one file to read from and it would be reused everytime a plot is needed.

Comment: Also, if I understand right from your answers, I can either make my own RAM disk (if possible at runtime), or make my own plotting function?

Comment: On a system where it is supported, `/dev/shm/` is usually RAM-based. Alternatively, tell `gnuplot` to read data from stdin (with e.g. `plot '<cat' ...`) and use `popen` to communicate with `gnuplot`.

Comment: Try [gnuplot-iostream](http://www.stahlke.org/dan/gnuplot-iostream/).

Comment: @Christoph Thanks for the link, though it looks like I need boost as a dependency. If I don't have to include external .so/.dll, this looks like a possible answer.

Comment: Can't you pipe the data to gnuplot, or do you need to do it from within the program?

Comment: @JonatanÖström I didn't know about that so, after a quick search, it turns out that it's supported in Windows, too(?). If so, maybe this is the solution? I'll search some more. Thank you for the hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So in Linux, using pipes, you could do the following as a first example:

```
cat data.txt | gnuplot -p -e "plot '-' w l"
```

where data.txt is a two column file. Instead of that file you can have your program produce some data and you could add an extra setting for gnuplot to make it slightly more involved:

```
./program | gnuplot -p -e "set ylabel 'E'; plot '-' w l"
```

Now this is all you need. Note that the `-p` = persistent, `-e` = interactive(?) and the semicolons (`;`) between the commands are required. Something similar might work in windows. I hope this helpts.

**Extra stuff:** If you have a lot of settings you can put them in a file, ex:

```
$ cat settings.txt
set logs;
set ylabel "hejsan";
set xlabel "energy";
plot '-' w l
```

and then:

```
./program | gnuplot -p -e "$(<settings.txt)"
```

Dont miss any symbols in `"$(<filename)"`! This might only apply to the Bash shell in Linux though. You can try the `cygwin` environment. Or just install ubuntu.

**EDIT a week later**

In case you want to do this to save your SSD, it of course wont hurt, but probably doesn't matter. The SSD's have intelligent management so it wont write to the same physical segment every time. The file would "move around", and they are built to last for hundreds of terabytes worth of cycling.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I have archlinux x64 and I'll try this in Windows, too, but not right now. It certainly looks like a valid option. I'll mark this as the answer.

Comment: Good, then it should work in Arch. Thanks for accepting, I think its my first!